# How to load images with list-style-image?

Tags: html, css, list

list-style-image somehow is not working for my HTML and CSS codes:

```
li {
    list-style-image: url('D:\HTML and CSS\imgs\plus.png');
}
```

Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: `list-style-image: url('D:\HTML%20and%20CSS\imgs\plus.png');`

Comment: don't use a file system path

Comment: Space is not allowed in urls. Remove space between html and css, correct the path accordingly.

Comment: I assume your css is not actually at that place in your code, right?

Comment: no, my css is in a separated file

Comment: hi @Ananda     list-style-image: url('D:\HTML%20and%20CSS\imgs\plus.png'); didn;t work. Thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
li {
    list-style-image: url('D:\HTML and CSS\imgs\plus.png');
}
```

The reason the list-style-image does NOT work is because the BACKWARD Slash in the URL.

So BACKWARD Slash should be replace with FORWARD slash as following:

```
li {
    list-style-image: url('D:/HTML and CSS/imgs/plus.png');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace spaces with `%20` in the `D:\HTML and CSS\` part of the path.

Example:
`list-style-image: url('D:\HTML%20and%20CSS\imgs\plus.png');`

Comment: Hi @Louie Thank you for your help. But it still didn't work.

Comment: Replace the li into ul.

ul {
    list-style-image: url('D:\HTML and CSS\imgs\plus.png');
    line-height: 1.6em;
}

Answer (score 0):

Ah!
The css URL is a **web url**, you've cited a path on your computer, it is currently not possible to directly cite a pathname without using the file protocol (or something else).
If you can use relative paths, this won't be an issue.

Comment: Hi @Henry7720. if url is not working in this case, what is the alternative? I am currently just doing some practice so everything is working on my computer. Thank you!

Comment: There are two fixes: put the images in the same folder as the index.html file. Otherwise, upload this image to imgur, and use the WEB URL of that image.

Answer (score 0):

@Bing Li, check this out.

```css
ul {
  color: #00948e;
  list-style-image: url('https://www.euronext.com/sites/euronext.com/themes/euronextV2Specific/images/plusButtonUp.gif'); /* Replace this image link   */
line-height: 1.6em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A Poetic Perspective</li>
  <li>Walt Whitman at War</li>
  <li>Found Poems and Outsider Poetry</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks @louierosero. That culprit was the backward slash. :)